# Why can't typescript infer types for my generic function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to type function so that I am able to infer the correct keys:

```js
type GroupedObject<T extends Record<string, string>> = {
  [K in keyof T & string as T[K] extends `${infer Group}-${infer Rest}` ? Group : never]: {
    [Key in keyof T as T[Key] extends `${K}-${infer Rest}` ? Key : never]: T[Key]
  }
}

export function groupObjectByPattern<T extends Record<string, string>>(obj: T): GroupedObject<T> {
  const groupedObject: GroupedObject<T> = {} as GroupedObject<T>

  for (const key in obj) {
    const [group] = key.split('-')

    if (!groupedObject[group]) {
      groupedObject[group] = {} as Pick<T, Extract<keyof T, `${string}-${string}`>>
    }

    groupedObject[group][key] = obj[key]
  }

  return groupedObject
}
```

By doing so, I should be able to achieve correct inference. e.g:

```js
const inputObject = {
  "color-background-primary": "#ffffff",
  "color-background-secondary": "#f3f4f4",
  "color-background-tertiary": "#e4e7e7",
  "color-background-interactive": "#0b968f",
  "color-background-hover": "#026661",
  "color-background-active": "#2079c3",
  "font-primary": "foo",
  "space-xs": "xs",
};

const groupedObject = groupObjectByPattern(inputObject);
groupedObject.color; // { "color-background-primary": string; "color-background-secondary": string; "color-background-tertiary": string; "color-background-interactive": string; "color-background-hover": string; "color-background-active": string; }
```

But I'm not getting any intellisence. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pasting your code in the [TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wk8pLw) shows 3 errors. You should try to provide an example that shows your problem.

Comment: Can you include the expected output for your `inputObject`?

Comment: @Cuzy That error is only related to `any`. It's not really an error, but more of TS config. It's the return type that's crucial

Comment: @wonderflame It's as simple as `inputObject`

Comment: @nas.engineer I mean the output. how should `groupedObject` look like?
`color: {'background-primary': '#ffffff'}`?

Comment: @wonderflame I've commented. So basically, it looks at the pattern of the key. See the object implementation. It groups them based on the first part of key (i.e. split by hyphen). TS should then infer.

i.e. `groupedObject.color; // { "color-background-primary": string; "color-background-secondary": string; "color-background-tertiary": string; "color-background-interactive": string; "color-background-hover": string; "color-background-active": string; }`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wyxkgm) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Looking into it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking `T[K]` where you should check `K`
Second check should be `${Group}-${infer Rest}` which is impossible in your code because it's lost on ternary.

```
type Split1<S extends string> = S extends `${infer F}-${string}` ? F : S;
type GroupedObject2<T> = {
  [K in Split1<keyof T & string>]: {
    [P in keyof T as P extends `${K}-${infer E}` ? E : never]: T[P]
  }
}
type Q = GroupedObject2<typeof inputObject>
//   ^?
// type Q = {
//     color: {
//         "background-primary": string;
//         "background-secondary": string;
//         "background-tertiary": string;
//         "background-interactive": string;
//         "background-hover": string;
//         "background-active": string;
//     };
//     font: {
//         ...;
//     };
//     space: {
//         ...;
//     };
// }
```

---

If you don't want to split child keys, it's even easier

```
type GroupedObject3<T> = {
  //                       inlined Pick<T, Extract<keyof T, `${K}-${string}`>>
  [K in Split1<keyof T & string>]: { [P in keyof T & `${K}-${string}`]: T[P]; }
}
type W = GroupedObject3<typeof inputObject>
//   ^?
// type W = {
//     color: {
//         "color-background-primary": string;
//         "color-background-secondary": string;
//         "color-background-tertiary": string;
//         "color-background-interactive": string;
//         "color-background-hover": string;
//         "color-background-active": string;
//     };
//     font: {
//         ...;
//     };
//     space: {
//         ...;
//     };
// }
```

Comment: Wow, it was more complicated than I thought. Thank you 